# Angular route accessible only through router.navigate

Tags: angular

Is it possible to create an Angular CanActivate Guard which will let an user to access the route only if I navigate to it through `router.navigate`?

Example:
User creates an account, and there are 2 components which can be shown: RegistrationForm and ConfirmationForm. Both of them have their specific route configured 'registrationForm', 'confirmationForm'. I want ConfirmationForm to be accessible only when the user go through RegistrationForm and on successful registration I use `router.navigate('confirmationForm')`. I want it to be blocked when the user puts www.someURL.com/confirmationForm in browser address bar.

Comment: Did you consider using a service to store a flag i.e.`canShowConfirmationForm`? Then you could set it in RegistrationForm and use in Guard.

Comment: Well I think I will do it this way because that is the best solution I found so far

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by jacekbj's comment to the original question,
this is how I did it:

First I created class CanShowConfirmationForm:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } 
from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CanShowConfirmationForm implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        const url: string = state.url;
        alert("current url" + this.router.url);

        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.router.url === "/register") { return true; }

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
    }
}
```

then I modified app routing module app-routing.module.ts by
importing just created class

```
import { CanShowConfirmationForm } from './can.show.confirmation.form';
```

and then I modified the route for component RegistrationSuccessComponent (In your example this component is named as ConfirmationForm) by adding property 
   CanActivate with value  [ CanShowConfirmationForm]:

```
{
 path: 'registration-success',
 canActivate: [ CanShowConfirmationForm],
 component: RegistrationSuccessComponent,
 data: { title: 'RegistrationSucess' }
}
```

(In your example successful registration is redirected to url /confirmationForm, in my example to url /registration-success.)

Now if I try to access directly to url http://localhost:4200/registration-success browser directs to url http://localhost:4200/login and after successful registration the registration-success view is shown. I think, this was what also you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine both forms into a single component, and use `*ngIf` to hide/show sections depending on registration result

Comment: I need a different route for both components.